# How to autoupdate chocolatey?

Tags: chocolatey

I have an old version of chocolatey (0.9.9.1) to manage windows packages.
How can I upgrade/update it to the latest version since I didn't installed it via chocolatey?

Answer (score 4):

Use the normal `upgrade` command.

```
choco upgrade chocolatey
```

Answer (score 1):

Chocolatey also has a shorter alias that you can use for upgrading packages: `cup chocolatey`

Or my favorite: `cup all -y`